# Error connecting an arduino and esp 32 via i2c

Tags: arduino, i2c, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, esp32

I'm having trouble connecting a esp32 with arduino pro mini 3v3. my code is the same arduino tutorial example. I use atom to code and when I open terminal serial write null message

Master code(Run ESP32)

```
 #include <Wire.h>
int i=0;
char c[20
];
#include <Wire.h>
#define I2C_SDA_PIN 21
#define I2C_SCL_PIN 22
void setup() {
  Wire.begin();        // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
  Serial.begin(9600);  // start serial for output
}

void loop() {
  Wire.requestFrom(8, 1);    // request 6 bytes from slave device #8

  while (Wire.available()>0) { // slave may send less than requested
     c[i]=Wire.read(); // receive a byte as character
     i++;
    Serial.print(c);         // print the character
  }
}
```

Run Arduino pro mini

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(8);                // join i2c bus with address #8
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); // register event
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}
// function that executes whenever data is requested by master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void requestEvent() {
  Wire.write('h'); // respond with message of 6 bytes
  // as expected by master
}
```

I did an i2c bus address test and recognized the arduino:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF5bz.png)
I do not find anything about it, if anyone can help

p.s sorry for my poor english.

Comment: You seem to have two copies of the same code here? It's a bit unclear what you're asking.

Comment: So, you're trying to run Arduino code on the ESP32, is that correct? Is there a reason you're not using the ESP-IDF?